# Unable to change password through token in android

Tags: android-studio, swagger

This is my RetrofitClientInstance - Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance implements Interceptor {

    private final Context context;

    public RetrofitClientInstance(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public static Retrofit getRetrofit() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl("http://api.employmentnew.c2k.in/")
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();

        return retrofit;
    }

    public static InterfaceAPI getService() {
        InterfaceAPI interfaceAPI = getRetrofit().create(InterfaceAPI.class);

        return interfaceAPI;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                .build();
        Response response =  chain.proceed(newRequest);
        Log.d("MyApp", "Code : "+response.code());
        if (response.code() == 401){
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            ((Activity) context).finish();
            return response;
        }

        return chain.proceed(newRequest);

    }
}
```

This is my MainMenuPage - Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class MainMenuPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    LoginResponse loginResponse;
    UpdatePasswordResponse updatePasswordResponse;

    TextView email2, rid2, menu;
    Button logout, modify_Updation,add_Details,add_Preference,change_Password,print_Certificate;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mySharedPrefManager";
    private static final String KEY_RID = "rid";
    private static final String TOKEN_KEY = "token";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_page);

        email2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email2);
        rid2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rid);
        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        modify_Updation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.modify_Updation);
        add_Details = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_Details);
        add_Preference = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_Preference);
        change_Password = (Button) findViewById(R.id.change_Password);
        print_Certificate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.print_Certificate);
        menu = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menu);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);

        String token = sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN_KEY, " ");

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.getExtras() != null){
            loginResponse = (LoginResponse) intent.getSerializableExtra("data");

            email2.setText("Email Address: " + loginResponse.getEmail());
            rid2.setText("Request ID: " + loginResponse.getRid());

            Log.e("Tag", "=======>" + loginResponse.getEmail());

        }

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainMenuPage.this, "Logout Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        modify_Updation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainMenuPage.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainMenuPage.this, "Modify Details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        change_Password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                if(intent.getExtras() != null) {

                    updatePasswordResponse = (UpdatePasswordResponse) intent.getSerializableExtra("token");

                    Log.e("Tag", "=======>" + loginResponse.getToken());
                }

                if (token!= null){
                    UpdatePasswordResponse updatePasswordResponse = new UpdatePasswordResponse();
                    updatePasswordResponse.setToken(token);
                }

                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChangePassword.class);
                Toast.makeText(MainMenuPage.this, "Change Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is my Login Response- Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class LoginResponse implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("TOKEN_KEY")
    private String token;
    private String rid;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getRid() {
        return rid;
    }

    public void setRid(String rid) {
        this.rid = rid;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

This is my UpdatepasswordResponse- Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class UpdatePasswordResponse implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("error")
    private boolean err;

    @SerializedName("message")
    private int msg;

    @SerializedName("TOKEN_KEY")
    private String token;

    private String email;
    private String oldPass;
    private String newPass;
    private String ConfirmPassword;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }



    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getOldPass() {
        return oldPass;
    }

    public void setOldPass(String oldPass) {
        this.oldPass = oldPass;
    }

    public String getNewPass() {
        return newPass;
    }

    public void setNewPass(String newPass) {
        this.newPass = newPass;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return ConfirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }



    public boolean isErr() {
        return err;

    }
}
```

This is my ChangePassword- Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class ChangePassword extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView change_Password, txt_email;
    EditText txt_OldPassword, txt_Password, txt_ConfirmPassword;
    Button btn_submit;
    Button logout;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mySharedPrefManager";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_password);

        change_Password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.change_Password);
        txt_OldPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.oldPass);
        txt_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPass);
        txt_ConfirmPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ConfirmPassword);
        txt_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
        logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);

        String email = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null);

        if (email != null){
            txt_email.setText(email);
        }

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();
                Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, "Logout successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }
        });

        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String oldPass = txt_OldPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String newPass = txt_Password.getText().toString().trim();
                String ConfirmPassword = txt_ConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (oldPass.isEmpty()) {
                    txt_OldPassword.setError("Please Enter Old Password");
                    txt_OldPassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                else if (newPass.isEmpty()) {
                    txt_Password.setError("Please Enter New Password");
                    txt_Password.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                else if (ConfirmPassword.isEmpty()){
                    txt_ConfirmPassword.setError("Please Enter Confirm Password");
                    txt_ConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                else{

                    UpdatePasswordResponse updatePasswordResponse = new UpdatePasswordResponse();
                    updatePasswordResponse.setOldPass(txt_OldPassword.getText().toString());
                    updatePasswordResponse.setNewPass(txt_Password.getText().toString());
                    updatePasswordResponse.setConfirmPassword(txt_ConfirmPassword.getText().toString());

                    Change_password(email,oldPass,newPass);

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void Change_password(String email, String oldPass, String newPass) {

       Call<UpdatePasswordResponse> updatePasswordResponseCall = RetrofitClientInstance.getService()
               .Change_password(email,oldPass,newPass);

        updatePasswordResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<UpdatePasswordResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UpdatePasswordResponse> call, Response<UpdatePasswordResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    UpdatePasswordResponse updatePasswordResponse = response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, "Password Change Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(ChangePassword.this, MainMenuPage.class)
                            .putExtra("token",updatePasswordResponse));
                    finish();

                } else {
                    String message = "An error required please try again later";
                    Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UpdatePasswordResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                String message = t.getLocalizedMessage();
                Toast.makeText(ChangePassword.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is my SharedPrefManager- Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class SharedPrefManager  {

    private static SharedPrefManager instance;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mySharedPrefManager";
    private static final String TOKEN_KEY = "token";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL ="email";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD ="password";
    private static final String KEY_RID ="rid";

    private SharedPrefManager(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static synchronized SharedPrefManager getInstance(Context context){
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new SharedPrefManager(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean LoginResponse(String email, String password, String rid, String token){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        editor.putString(KEY_RID, rid);
        editor.putString(TOKEN_KEY, token);
        editor.apply();

        return true;

    }

    public static String getToken(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN_KEY, null);
    }

    public static void setToken(Context context, String token) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN_KEY, token);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null) != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean logout(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.apply();
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my MainActivity- Unable to change password through token in android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText email1, password1;
    private TextView login_form, disclaimer;
    private Button login, ForgetPassword, registration, ForgetPasswordSearch;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    private static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "mySharedPrefManager";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String TOKEN_KEY = "token";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        email1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        login_form = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        ForgetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ForgetPassword);
        ForgetPasswordSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ForgetPasswordSearch);
        registration = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registration);
        disclaimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.disclaimer);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        String email = sharedPreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL,null);
        String token = sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN_KEY, null);


        if (email != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangePassword.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (token != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL,email1.getText().toString());
                editor.putString(TOKEN_KEY, token);
                editor.apply();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email1.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password1.getText().toString())) {
                    String message = "All inputs required";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
                    loginRequest.setEmail(email1.getText().toString());
                    loginRequest.setPassword(password1.getText().toString());

                    loginUser(loginRequest);

                }

            }

        });
    }

    public void loginUser(LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = RetrofitClientInstance.getService().loginUser(loginRequest);
        loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful())   {
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainMenuPage.class).putExtra("data",loginResponse));
                    finish();


                } else {
                    String message = "An error required please try again later";
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                String message = t.getLocalizedMessage();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }


}
```

This is my interfaceapi- Unable to change password through token in android

```
public interface InterfaceAPI {



    @POST("Login/Login")
    Call<LoginResponse> loginUser(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);

    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8"})

    @GET("Candidate/ChangePassword")
    Call<UpdatePasswordResponse> Change_password(@Query(encoded = true, value = "email") @NotNull String email,
                                                 @Query("oldPass") String oldPass,
                                                 @Query("newPass") String newPass

    );



}
```

Comment: Hi! Instead of posting all your code, try to post where you think the error is and explain what you are doing there.

Comment: @adrisons sir, I want to understand how token work, in my case, after log in the app, token shown in logcat but when I print/get this token they show null. That's why, I am unable to change my password which gives error 401 unauthorized. Sir please explain the full process of change password via token with request header. Sir, please look up my code once, I am grateful to you.